# Self executing function inheritance

Tags: javascript

I would like to know how to make `child` get the prototype methods from both itself and `base`.

Also, there any way to do

```
child.prototype = Object.create(base.prototype);
child.prototype.constructor = child;
```

inside of the `child` IIFE, rather than outside of it.

```
var base = (function(){

    var cls = function(){

    };

    cls.prototype = {
        doStuff: function(){
            console.log('dostuff');
        }
    };

    return cls;

})();

var child = (function(){

    var cls = function(){
        base.call(this);    
    };

    cls.prototype = {
        doOtherStuff: function(){
            console.log('doOtherStuff');
        }
    };

    return cls;

})();

child.prototype = Object.create(base.prototype);
child.prototype.constructor = child;

var b = new child();
b.doStuff();
b.doOtherStuff();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9uGsA/

Comment: put them both in the same iife...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to know how to make child get the prototype methods from both itself and base.

1. Do `child.prototype = Object.create(base.prototype);` before setting up child prototype.
2. Instead of doing `cls.prototype = ...`, add properties to `cls.prototype` one at a time.

> Also, there any way to do [inheritance] inside of the `child` IIFE, rather than outside of it.

Of course, just use `cls` instead of `child`.

http://jsfiddle.net/7uCwz/

Bonus fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7uCwz/1/

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if it's possible to define properties using the object notation like in my example, without overriding the other properties on the prototype? `$.extend()` perhaps?

Comment: @Johan not without iterating over the properties and copying them into the real prototype. You've already set the prototype to an object with the parent prototype in its prototype chain; if you set it to something else, you lose the inheritance.

Comment: Right, oh well... Thanks for elaborating

Answer (score 1):

Define a function http://jsfiddle.net/9uGsA/1/

```
function inherit(base, child, proto) {
    child.prototype = Object.create(base.prototype);
    child.prototype.constructor = child;

    proto&&Object.keys(proto).forEach(function(key){
        child.prototype[key] = proto[key];    
    })

}
```

and use it like this

```
var child = (function(){

    var cls = function(){
        base.call(this);    
    };

    inherit(base, cls, {doOtherStuff: function(){
            console.log('doOtherStuff');
    }});


    return cls;

})();
```

Answer (score 0):

New simpler answer:

```
//test inheritance
//parent class
var mom = function(name){
    this.momsname = name;
}
mom.prototype.getMomsName = function(){ return this.momsname; }

//child class
var kid = function(mother,name){
    this.sonsname = name;
    //call the parent
    mom.call(this,mother);
}
//add the parent's methods
kid.prototype = new mom();
//point the constructor to the child
kid.prototype.constructor = kid;
kid.prototype.getKidsName = function() { return this.sonsname }
//instatiate the child
var son = new kid("Mary","Tom");
//use only the child's methods
var temp2 = "Son's name: " + son.getKidsName() + ". Mother's Name: " + son.getMomsName() + ".";
//temp now holds "Son's name: Tom. Mother's Name: Mary."
```