# Passing arguments to a Javascript IIFE constructor

Tags: javascript, inheritance, constructor, iife

I'm trying to get my head around Javascript OO, using the IIFE module pattern to mimic a class:

```
var MyClass = (function() {
  // Constructor
  return function() {
    return {
      foo: 'foo'
    }
  }
}());
```

I'm passing arguments with something like:

```
var MyClass = (function() {
  // Constructor
  return function(arg) {
    return {
      foo: function() {
        return 'foo'+arg
      }
    }
  }
}());
```

To mimic classical inheritance I am using the pattern suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20402984/self-executing-function-inheritance):

```
function inherit(base, child, obj) {
  child.prototype = Object.create(base.prototype);
  child.prototype.constructor = child;
  obj&&Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key){
    child.prototype[key] = obj[key];
  })
}

var Base = (function() {

  var init = function() {};

  init.prototype = {
    foo: function() {
      return "foo";
    }
  };

  return init;

}());

var Child = (function() {

  var init = function() {
    Base.call(this); 
  };

  inherit(Base, init, {
    bar: function() {
      return 'bar';
    }
  });

  return init;

}());
```

So far so good. My only problem is in understanding how to pass parameters to my class constructor when I'm doing inheritance in the above way. I like the fact that in the 'pure' IIFE module I can simply refer to the constructor parameter in any functions defined within it, so that they become closures. But how do I access constructor params when I'm adding these subsequent functions using the constructor variable, as in the inheritance example above? I suppose I could do something like:

```
var init = function(arg) {
  this.theArg = arg;
};
```

Then I can access it within anything subsequent:

```
init.prototype = {
    foo: function() {
      return "foo"+this.theArg;
    }
  };
```

And for the child:

```
var init = function(arg) {
    Base.call(this, arg); 
  };
```

This makes `arg` available to the outside world, so to make it read-only I suppose a getter would work:

```
var init = function(arg) {
    var theArg = arg;
    this.getArg = function() { return theArg };
  };
```

On the face of it I can't see anything wrong with that, and I can't think of a better alternative. Is there one? Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: First, IMO your code seems complex to little benefit if any. I don't really understand why you're doing it that way. Second, your `init` function has no access to `base`, which is defined in the `inherit` function, so it won't run anyway. Third, your overall question seems unclear to me. I think it's getting lost in all your explanation of your inheritance. Are you just asking if it's a good idea to expose data via a getter function instead of as a property?

Comment: @squint This is not my 'real' code, it's just to show the patterns I'm using, for purposes of clarity. I don't think there's anything unnecessarily complex there, these are all patterns that seem to be used extensively 'in the wild' ( the IIFE module pattern). And the inheritance example is copied almost exactly from the post I linked to. Re-reading what I wrote, however, I think I answered my own question in the final example.

Comment: I think the best thing here is probably to accept that JavaScript does not have access modifiers and put data belonging to the object directly on said object. This will save a lot of complexity (and be easy to rewrite to ES6 classes, because it seems like you’ll go that way).

Comment: @RyanO'Hara As far as I understand privacy can be achieved using the IIFE module pattern. In the last code example `theArg` is not accessible from outside, but the accessor `getArg()` is (am I right?). But I'll admit my question was confusing, and much more basic than the glut of code examples suggests. Really I was simply asking how to reference a variable/property defined with `init` from another part of the IIFE outside its scope. And the answer, it seems,  is with `this`.

Comment: I guess if you're going to actually make use of those IIFEs, it would make more sense but as written, they serve no real purpose. It would be no different to simply create the constructors and update their prototypes. Also, all your constructors are named `init`, which is not going to be helpful with debugging in the console. As for code in the wild, *sometimes* there's the cargo cult effect, and sometimes you may see code created from a generator like TypeScript, which at times uses unnecessary constructs for simplicity. Hard to say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can't think of a better alternative. Is there one?

No. Not in your example.

> I like the fact that in the 'pure' IIFE module I can simply refer to the constructor parameter in any functions defined within it, so that they become closures.

You can access `args` in each function because, in your first example, you are defining `foo` on each object instance separately. Therefore each definition of `foo` has a separate closure containing the `args` passed when it was defined.

This is also only possible, because `foo` is defined within the scope containing your `args`.

> But how do I access constructor params when I'm adding these subsequent functions ... in the inheritance example above?

By using the classical inheritance patten you found, you are now defining the `foo` function on the constructor prototype. This means that only a single `foo` definition exists which is inherited by all instances created using your constructor. So `foo` can not be made specific to each instance anymore.

As you have figured, it also means `foo` is no longer defined inside the scope containing `args` and has no direct access.

You are therefore correct by assigning `args` to `this.thisArgs` which allows `foo` to access `thisArgs` on each instance. You have made `foo` a general case function that can handle any instance it is applied to.

**Passing arguments to the IIFE constructor:** The IIFE itself is not the constructor, it simply  builds the constructor object. The IIFE's scope has long since been returned by the time the constructor itself is invoked.

> Am I missing something obvious?

Yes. Javascript is a **prototypical** language. It was never meant to be like "classical" languages. Just let it be Javascript. :)

Comment: Thanks. By 'constructor' I indeed meant the internal constructor object. Apologies for the lack of clarity.